# Nav Link does not trigger custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, tsx

I'm fairly new to React and am following a tutorial to train myself.

The problem I'm having is that I have several routes rendering the same component with different props, but the component doesn't seem to be mounted/dismounted when navigating using NavLink. So my custom hook isn't triggered and it's as if we haven't navigated.

If I manually refresh the page after navigation, the component is correctly updated.
I use `react@18.2.0` and `react-router-dom@6.16.0`.

- `index.tsx`

  ```js
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
  import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
  import './index.css';
  import App from './App';

  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
  );
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
  ```
- `App.tsx`

  ```js
  import React from 'react';
  import { Header } from "./components";
  import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
  import { MovieList } from "./pages";

  function App() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<MovieList />} />
          <Route path="/movies/bottom" element={<MovieList sort='bottom' />} />
          <Route path="/movies/unpopular" element={<MovieList sort='unpopular' />} />
          <Route path="/movies/upcoming" element={<MovieList sort='upcoming' />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  }

  export default App;
  ```
- Into the `Header.tsx` component, I have :

  ```js
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/" className={linkClass} aria-current="page" end>Recent</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/movies/unpopular" className={linkClass}>Unpopular</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/movies/bottom" className={linkClass}>Bottom Rated</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/movies/upcoming" className={linkClass}>Upcoming</NavLink>
  </li>
  ```
- `MovieList.tsx`

  ```js
  import { useState } from "react";
  import { Card } from "../components";
  import { MovieService } from "../services/Movie.service";

  type MovieListProps = {
    sort?: MovieService.defaultSort;
  }

  export function MovieList({ sort }: MovieListProps = {}) {
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
      defaultSort: sort
    });
    const movies = MovieService.useGet(filter);

    return (
      <main>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter({defaultSort: 'now_playing'})}>Recent</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter({defaultSort: 'unpopular'})}>unpopular</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter({defaultSort: 'bottom'})}>Bottom Ratted</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter({defaultSort: 'upcoming'})}>Upcoming</button>
        <section className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4">
          {
            movies.data?.results.map((movie, index) => (
              <Card key={index} item={movie}/>
            ))
          }
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
  ```

Here, the `movies` object isn't updated when I click on the NavLink from the header, but I've added some buttons that call setFilter, and when I click on those buttons, it works fine, why?

You can find the code of the tutorial that works here : [github](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/React-JS-Masterclass---Go-From-Zero-To-Job-Ready/tree/main/react-ul-main/071/src)

I have diff because I'm doing it with Typescript and I isolated the code to fetch the APIs in a different way, you can find my currently code here : [github](https://github.com/lucaspouchot/nanar-finder/tree/bugfix/navlink-unmount)

But I still don't understand why my implementation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-Router optimizes to keep React components mounted. In other words, it tries to not do any extra work to unmount and remount the same React component if it can help it. In React, triggering a component rerender is less effort than remounting.

You can add a `useEffect` hook to update the `filter` state when the `sort` prop value changes:

```
export function MovieList({ sort }: MovieListProps = {}) {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ defaultSort: sort });

  useEffect(() => {
    setfilter({ defaultSort: sort });
  }, [sort]);

  const movies = MovieService.useGet(filter);

  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter({ defaultSort: 'now_playing' })}>
        Recent
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter({ defaultSort: 'unpopular' })}>
        unpopular
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter({ defaultSort: 'bottom' })}>
        Bottom Ratted
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter({ defaultSort: 'upcoming' })}>
        Upcoming
      </button>
      <section className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4">
        {movies.data?.results.map((movie, index) => (
          <Card key={index} item={movie} />
        ))}
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Or you could give each "instance" of the `MovieList` component a unique React key so the component remounts when the route changes.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MovieList key="none" />} />
        <Route
          path="/movies/bottom"
          element={<MovieList key="bottom" sort="bottom" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/movies/unpopular"
          element={<MovieList key="unpopular" sort="unpopular" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/movies/upcoming"
          element={<MovieList key="upcoming" sort="upcoming" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here, the movies object isn't updated when I click on the NavLink from
> the header, but I've added some buttons that call setFilter, and when
> I click on those buttons, it works fine, why?

The updates are not seen as the `.map` will never reflect them because the `const movies` you are trying to map are not in a state variable managed by the `useState` hook, so any changes in movies value after the initial render are being ignored. In order to solve this issue, you should create a `useState` hook, and then get the data (presumably a fetch so make sure to use async/await) and set the state value so that your `.map` function would rerender on a state change.

```
const [movies, setMovies]
...
setMovies(*desired value*)
```

> I've added some buttons that call setFilter, and when I click on those buttons, it works fine, why?

When you update the filter state value with setFilter, it causes the component to rerender, and your updated `const movies` becomes visable as by that time it has a changed value.

Comment: I didn't show the code for `MovieService.useGet` and forgot to mention it, but it's a custom hook, with its parameters as dependencies, so if I understand correctly, I don't need to use a `useState` to manage `movies`.`(https://github.com/lucaspouchot/nanar-finder/blob/bugfix/navlink-unmount/src/services/Movie.service.ts)

Comment: @Taine No, you wouldn't want to duplicate the fetched data into another local state. If you needed, you could likely use the `useMemo` hook in your custom hook to memoize the fetched result so consuming components receive a stable reference.